# sed slice and append lines in a file

Tags: linux, text, sed, replace

I have a file lets call it `text` (BTW I'm on linux) and the file contains 2 numbers and an unknown number of names.

```
1
2
Name 1
Name 2
Name 3
```

Is it possible to slice the part after the numbers and append the new names? The new ones can be less or more names than in the example.

Expected output:

```
//Pseudo code
names = {"new name1","new name2"}; //Array with the new names (can be a file too)

//test-File after sed
1
2
new name1
new name2
```

Comment: Can you provide the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Aif Added the expected output

Comment: my 2 cents: instead of overwrite, slice and append.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "new names" ? I think you did not describe any changes or file updates. Can you give pairs (old/new) of sample input? With accompanying expected output? In contrast to Karoly, I am not sure what the two of you mean by "slice". Is the first part of the pseudo code (the array with new names) input or output? What have you tried? What is your output? What makes your output unsatisfying?

Comment: @Yunnosch its solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
DATA=("new name1" "new name2 "new name3" "new name4" "new name5" "new name6")
PATH="/etc/conffile"
SERVER_IP="192.168.x.x"

for (( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )); do
    COMMAND="sed -i $((${i} + 3))s/.*/${DATA[${i}]}/"
    rsh ${SERVER_IP} ${COMMAND} ${PATH}
done
```